# Как хранить разные массивы в БД

Tags: база-данных, массивы, php, mysql

Нужен ваш совет, в общем имеются данные, которые хранятся в виде ассоциативного массива PHP, данные разнообразные и даже ключи у них разные. В двух словах это тарифы продуктов, как можно этот массив засунуть в одно поле и потом извлечь из него? У меня идеи только записать их туда в поле TEXT и потом парсить, но это "дорогостоящая" операция получится. Разработка идет на PHP в качестве БД используется MySQL.

Comment: Блин, вопрос в принципе можно считать снятым. Забыл про serialize() и unserialize().

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать модель хранения eav. Но нужно смотреть, что за данные, возможно что-то поддается нормализации.

Comment: Спасибо. Я проверил уже, ассоциативные массивы прекрасно сохраняются в бинарных полях, если их пропустить через serialize(). Ну и обратно получаются тоже нормально через unserialize().